# Using Spring WebSockets to Update MySQL Database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

I'm currently working on an application where the goal is essentially to create a clone of Slack using Spring Boot for the back end. I know I need to use web sockets for the real-time messaging but I can't figure out exactly how to to set it up.

Is it possible to set up a socket connection between the client and my server so that new messages are automatically added to/read from the database in real time? Or is that not the right way to approach the problem at all? Any advice/resource recommendations are greatly appreciated.

I've done a fair amount of research but all I've been able to find are very simple tutorials/articles showing making applications that are more akin to a public chatroom where everyone just posts in the same chat and messages aren't persisted outside of a simple in-memory message broker. While those were helpful for understanding some basic concepts I'm having a hard time applying any of that information to a more complex use-case. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: In your case, Instead of enabling simpleMessageBroker you should use rabbitmq or kafka. You can get the messages stored in rabbitmq queue and then intercept those request to collect the messages you want to store